# How to get all the dates and name of days of a particular month of an year in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to print all the dates and name of days of a particular month of an year in PHP. I am trying to use `cal_days_in_month` function, but unable to achieve my desired functionality. Please suggest me the way.

```
<?php
$number_of_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 7, 2016);
for ($x = 1; $x <= $number_of_days; $x++) 
{
    echo "<p>Day: ".$x."</p>";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Day: 1
Day: 2
...
...
Day: 31
```

Is there a way, I can get output like this:

```
Day: July 1, 2016 (Friday)
Day: July 2, 2016 (Saturday)
...
...
Day: July 31, 2016 (Sunday)
```

Comment: You could use `strtotime();` It has a 1+ day function which you could loop, something like `$day = strtotime('July 1 2016', '+1 day');` and then use `date(<FORMAT>,$day);` to display the output as you want it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$number_of_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month, $year);
for ($x = 1; $x <= $number_of_days; $x++) {
    echo date("F", strtotime($x . "-" . $month . "-" . $year)) . " " . $x . "," . $year . "(" . date("l", strtotime($x . "-" . $month . "-" . $year)) . ")<br/>";
}
```

output:

```
July 1,2016(Friday)
July 2,2016(Saturday)
July 3,2016(Sunday)
July 4,2016(Monday)
July 5,2016(Tuesday)
July 6,2016(Wednesday)
July 7,2016(Thursday)
July 8,2016(Friday)
July 9,2016(Saturday)
July 10,2016(Sunday)
July 11,2016(Monday)
July 12,2016(Tuesday)
July 13,2016(Wednesday)
July 14,2016(Thursday)
July 15,2016(Friday)
July 16,2016(Saturday)
July 17,2016(Sunday)
July 18,2016(Monday)
July 19,2016(Tuesday)
July 20,2016(Wednesday)
July 21,2016(Thursday)
July 22,2016(Friday)
July 23,2016(Saturday)
July 24,2016(Sunday)
July 25,2016(Monday)
July 26,2016(Tuesday)
July 27,2016(Wednesday)
July 28,2016(Thursday)
July 29,2016(Friday)
July 30,2016(Saturday)
July 31,2016(Sunday)
```